# Editing Class permission schema not working (REST)

Tags: quickblox

By following the instructions given in http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Permissions
every new record created (using REST interface) seems to get the ORIGNAL Class permission values instead of the edited ones.

In addition to this, the "use class permission" check box makes no difference on those problematic records. If a single record is created or edited using the web admin panel, then the permissions are working on the client app also.

Thanks
Janne

Answer (score 0):

I see some misunderstanding in your explanation.

Class Permissions and Records permissions - they aren't related to each other.
If you edit Class Permissions, then Records permissions won't be touched. 
And vice-a-versa.

If you don't use  "use class permission" check box - then  Records permissions will be used to determine access level of the record

If you on "use class permission" check box - then Class Permissions (that you set in Admin panel) will be used to determine access level of the record and Records permissions will be ignored.

Default Record permissions are:

- Read: Open
- Update: Owner
- Delete: Owner

Got it?

Comment: Thanks for your response Igor.  

I assumed that every new records "default" permissions would be inherited from the current Class Permissions. If not what are the default Record permissions?

For some reason, when we where testing the "use class permission" check box, we did not get access to a record. Only after changing manually that records permissions, we got the correct results in our client.

Thanks

Comment: Added default record permissions